# How can a return a blank value for my Enum

Tags: swift, enums

I've set an Enum for my support types which is declared like this

```
enum SupportType: String, Codable {
    case type1
    case type2
    case type3

    func string() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .type1:
                return "Type 1"
            case .type2:
                return "Type 2"
            case .type3:
                return "Type 3"
    }
}
```

When I'm adding to my class I declare type as

```
type: SupportType
```

This all works when values are passed but when I try to send a blank new type I've tried declaring it as

```
NewType(name: data.name, supportType: [SupportType(rawValue: "")], supportName: "")
```

This throws an error saying it has an empty value. How can I declare a new type without using one of the existing type values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `nil`?

First declare your property as optional:

```
var type: SupportType?
```

And then you can pass nil:

```
NewType(name: data.name, supportType: nil, supportName: "")
```

Comment: It throws an error 'Nil is not compatible with expected type SupportType'

Comment: @LeoDabus But OP declared the property as `SupportType`, not `[SupportType]`.

Comment: @user616076 You need to first change the declaration to `SupportType?`. Did you do that?

Comment: @user616076 Also, if you are using a custom initializer, change the parameter type to optional as well.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of an `enum` is that it can only be instantiated with one of its predefined and immutable cases. An `enum` type can only take the values that are defined at compile type, you cannot add any more cases to it after the type has been declared and you cannot modify its existing cases.

Your `string` function also makes no sense, you should simply overwrite the default `rawValue` of your `enum`, then access the property you currently access using `string` with `rawValue`.

```
enum SupportType: String, Codable {
    case type1 = "Type 1"
    case type2 = "Type 2"
    case type3 = "Type 3"
}
```

If you define a property of type `SupportType` for another type, you should define that as an optional instead of trying to create a "blank value" for `SupportType`. You should also modify your custom initializer to take an optional input argument for `supportType`.

```
class NewType {
    let name:String
    var supportType:SupportType?
    var supportName:String?

    init(name: String, supportType: SupportType? = nil, supportName: String? = nil){
        self.name = name
        self.supportType = supportType
        self.supportName = supportName
    }
}
```

Then call it as

```
NewType(name: data.name, supportType: nil, supportName: nil)
```